# Can the cooling fan in laptop or ceiling fan shaft fail as result of critical speed? But that's not often the case, even if they rotate at high speed

Tags: mechanical-engineering, mechanical-failure

Cooling fan in PC start very fast. Is there any chance of it's failure due to resonance? In opposite, ceiling fan starts very slow, why doesn't it fail by resonance? Does regulator have any arrangement for crossing resonant speed quickly. Same question applies to cooling fan, how designer ensures it never stay at critical speed.

Comment: is the working rpm range lower than the critical speed?

Comment: `Is there any chance?` ... there is always a chance ... it may be almost non-existent, but it's there

Comment: My pc is an old top-notch pc from 2014 with so many programs installed that make moving on to a new PC a horror. last 3 years when I start to put an extra processing load on the CPU, and GPU, the fan vibrates wildly and makes a screeching, grinding noise.  sofar a tap has been able to stop the resonance! or i just remove the load from GPU.

Comment: @kamran that is bad bearings, not natural resonance

Comment: I agree with @jsotola. PC fans almost always fail because of bearings. "Screeching, grinding noise" is what it usually sounds like.

Comment: @SolarMike But how should I calculate critical speed in both case? If you know some, pls explain me with example and values.

Comment: @jsotola but why it's almost non-existent. I need more details and reason for clarity of this statement.

Comment: my apologies, but I do not understand what you said ... what is almost non-existent?

Comment: @jsotola you said resonance is non existent in cooling fan and failure occurs due to bad bearings. But why is that so? Suppose I used best bearings by considering the aim of checking failure of cooling fan due to resonance only, then when it will fail? If any law or formula is there then it will be much better. Same question for ceiling fan but I somewhat agree with SolarMike answer for ceiling fan that it rotates below critical speed so no chance of resonance in ceiling fan. Still if anyone explain the same with real life example and values, then I will be grateful.

Comment: @Mr.Mechanical I was referring to `the fan vibrates wildly and makes a screeching, grinding noise` ... that is a description of bad bearings, not a resonating fan ... I did not mean to imply that resonance is non-existent ... there is some level of resonance in everything